# Partially order a list Python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I am working on a python project where I would like to order the header of a pandas dataframe in some pattern. 
My resultant list looks as below:

```
Match1 attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 ... attributeN Score1 Match2 attributeM Score2 ... Match3 Score3
```

I would like to order the elements of the list in the following pattern

```
Match1 Score1 Match2 Score2 Match3 Score3 attribute1 attribute2 attributeN ...
```

I know how many pairs of Match/Score there are in the list. But I dont know how many attributes there will be (I don't need to order them though). These are all determined by the particular structure of data. Is there a way for me to rearrange the order of such a list?

Thanks!

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sorted`, you can specify keys as follows; The first key sort attribute columns to the end, and the second key sort the result by the number at the end of the strings:

```
# cols = df.columns
cols = ['Match1', 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attributeN', 'Score1', 'Match2', 'attributeM', 'Score2', 'Match3', 'Score3']

import re
sorted(cols, key=lambda x: (not bool(re.match('match|score', x, flags=re.I)), re.sub(r'.*(\d+)$', r'\1', x)))

#['Match1',
# 'Score1',
# 'Match2',
# 'Score2',
# 'Match3',
# 'Score3',
# 'attribute1',
# 'attribute2',
# 'attribute3',
# 'attributeM',
# 'attributeN']
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. However, the attributes are not this structured. They have a mix of names. Is there still a way to do it by modifying the method?

Comment: You can make the key the other way around; If you are sure the match and score columns starts with match and score, then you can check them and negate the bool value, it should give you similar results.

Comment: This works very well! Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some incomplete code to start with

```
index = 0
for i in range(num_matches_and_scores]:
  match1 = ??? # First instance of whatever you are trying to find
  list1.remove(match1)
  list1.insert(index, match1)
  index += 1
  score1 = ???
  list1.remove(score1)
  list1.inset(index, score1)
  index += 1
```

Comment: I got the idea and let me try to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: If this is the most helpful answer, I would greatly appreciate it if you marked it as accepted. :)